# Injecting Spring managed beans in EJBs and injecting EJBs in Spring Controllers

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, ejb, ear, multi-module

I am getting `NullpointerException` when calling EJB

Issue relates more to ways of configuring EJBs so that they can be injected in spring Controllers and Injecting Service classes into EJBs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all beans defined are known to spring application context
A work around to injecting beans in EJBs is to use `@PostContruct`, this is the only way I could get everything working but a better example of a working setup could be more appreciated.